# Orthogonal projection of the form I - V where I is identity matrix and V is also matrix of the same size as I

Tags: linear-algebra

I have come across a few papers which talk about creating an orthogonal projection and use the following algebra to create one:

$\textbf{U} = \textbf{I} - \textbf{V} $

where $\textbf{I}$ is the identity matrix and $\textbf{V}$ is the same size as I (obviously).

I was wondering if someone can clearly explain the geometry behind the above equation.  Assume a background of the reader of early college level linear algebra.

A small example perhaps in R2 or R3 would be helpful to explain.

Comment: Is $U$ or $V$ a projection? In other words, is $V^2=V$ or $U^2=U$ (the defining property of projection)? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections

Comment: @jobe V is a projection. You can reference step 17 in Algorithm 1 of this paper if you're very curious. http://www.lx.it.pt/~bioucas/files/ieeegrsVca04.pdf

Comment: Without chasing the link to the paper, I would guess that $V$ is an orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of the space onto which you’re projecting. If the complement has a smaller dimension, it’s often easier to construct that projection directly.

Comment: @amd what does this mean geometrically?

Comment: You can decompose any vector into the sum of its orthogonal projection onto a subspace and a vector orthogonal to that subspace. You can therefore compute the projection by subtracting this orthogonal component from the original vector.

Comment: @amd where does the identity matrix come from?

Comment: $v-Av=Iv-Av=(I-A)v$.